# Ajax result shows empty return on console

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having this problem.  I use ajax to post values to php.  The scripts works fine, but when I use console.log(result) it shows that the result returns empty.  It's for a date field on my form.  Here is my input field code:`<input type="date" name="bday" class="bday" placeholder="Enter birthday" required="true" />`.  I then post the information to this code that does the error handling:
                `

```
public function validatebday($bday){
                //Check if date is valid
                $valid_date = validateDate($bday);

                if($valid_date != true){
                    return 'Not a valid date!';
                } elseif ($valid_date === true) {
                    //Check if the birthday valid
                    $dob = new DateTime($bday);
                    $age = $dob->diff(new DateTime);
                    $age = $age->y;

                    if($age < 4){
                        return 'You are too young!';
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } //End age check`
```

My jquery script looks like this:

```
//Checking the birthday
self.config.bdayInput.on('blur', function(){
    let bdate = new Date($.trim(self.config.bdayInput.val()));
    let day = ("0" + bdate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    let month = ("0" + (bdate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    let bday = bdate.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
    console.log(bday);
    $.ajax({
        data: 'bday=' +bday,
        success: function(result){
            result = $.trim(result);
            console.log(result);
            //Check if the user is old enough
            if(result === 'You are too young!'){
                self.config.bdayerrdiv.addClass('signuperrdiv');
                self.config.bdayerrSpan.addClass('erroroutput').text(result);
                self.config.bdayErr = true;
                return;
            };

            //Checks if the date is a valid date
            if(result === 'Not a valid date!'){
                self.config.bdayerrdiv.addClass('signuperrdiv');
                self.config.bdayerrSpan.addClass('erroroutput').text(result);
                self.config.bdayErr = true;
                return;                        
            };
        }
    });
```

When the date is not correct it get the error and if the age is too young I get the error, but if both pass I get this on my console:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can fix this please?

Here is my code that validate the date:

```
function validateDate($input_date){

    /*
     * This function does not take in account when the user capture the name of the month instead of the number, eg: Jan, Feb as there are way too many variants for this.  This function is based on the standard format on how the date is stored in Mysql which is yyyy-mm-dd
     */

    //Convert the input date Year, month and day.
    $date = explode('-', $input_date);

    //Split date into YYYY-MM-DD to work with
    $year = (int)$date[0];
    $month = (int)$date[1];
    $day = (int)$date[2];

    //Check is all parameters in the date string is numeric
    if(!is_numeric($year) || !is_numeric($month) || !is_numeric($day)){
        //Return false if any of them is not numeric
        return false;
    }

    //Checks that the year has got 4 digists
    if(strlen($year) < 4){
        return false;
    }

    //Get the leap years from 1700 up to the year that is part of the date string
    //Set initial count
    $count = 0;

    //Set the intervals to determine each leap year.
    $interval = 4;

    //Placeholder to hold leap years.
    $leap_years = array();

        //Loop through the days to determine the leap years.  We start checking from the year 1692 until the year that was entered in the input date.
    for($i = 1692; $i <= $year;$i++ ){
        if($count === $interval){
            $leap_years[] .= $count + $i;
            //Reset count back to 0
            $count = 0;
        }
        //Increment the count.
        $count++;
    }

    //Set the first day of the month
    $first_day_of_month = 1;

    //Determine the last day of the month
    if($month == 1 || $month == 3 || $month == 5 || $month == 7 || $month ==8 || $month == 10 || $month == 12){
        //Set the value for the last day of the month.
        $last_day_of_month = 31;
    }elseif($month == 4 || $month == 6 || $month == 9 || $month == 11){
        //Set the value for the last day of the month.
        $last_day_of_month = 30;
    }elseif($month == 2){
        //Check if the year is a leap year
        if(in_array($year, $leap_years)){
            //Set the last day to 29
            $last_day_of_month = 29;
        }else{
            //Set the last day to 28
            $last_day_of_month = 28;
        }
    }

    //Check the valid first and last days of the month
    if($day < $first_day_of_month){
        //Return false if the day is smaller than 0
        return false;
    }

    //Check if the month if from 1 to 12
    if($month < 1 || $month > 12){
        //Return false of the month is from 1 to 12.
        return false;
    }

    //Check for a valid end date
    if($day > $last_day_of_month){
        //Return false if the day is bigger than the last day of the specific month
        return false;
    }
    //Return true if all the checks passed
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but where are you telling the ajax funciton what URL to request?  And what are you _expecting_ the console to show when there's no error?  I'm not seeing any output from your PHP in the non-error case.  Actually, the shown PHP doesn't output anything.  You should show the code that calls `validatebday()`.

Comment: Sorry, here is the part url part: `var sign_up_student = {

    init: function(config){
        this.config = config;
 
        this.bindEvents();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            url: 'assets/common/validatesignupfrm.php',
            type: 'POST'
        });
    },`

Comment: Please update your question with any relevant information (including the other answers to my questions).  As you can see, it is rather hard to read code in comments.

Comment: @Patrick Q How do I update my question and include your other answers please?

Comment: See that [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53179666/edit) link?

Comment: Thanks I added the code :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  I don't so much care about the `validateDate()` code.  I care about the code that _calls_ `validatebday()`.  I also want to know what result you are _expecting_.

Comment: I call the function in the first code snippet called `public function validatebay($bday){ $valid_date = validateDate($bday); ...`

Comment: The result I expecting from the function is either true or false.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you seem to be having trouble understanding what I'm saying.  I'm not sure if it's a language issue or what, but unfortunately I'm not going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP script you return `true` if the validation passes. When this is returned via your jQuery function you're getting no 'real' response. Ie. In your PHP script, instead of returning `true`, return `"valid"` (as a string) and see if that appears in your `console.log()`.